# How to change color of Indeterminate ProgressBar in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

How can I change color of Indeterminate ProgressBar in Windows phone?
I have tried setting the background and border brush to null and change the foreground to black:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" IsIndeterminate="True" Foreground="Black" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
```

But when I run it, it still has blue as the animation dots moving across the screen.

Comment: Have tried your code and it shows black dots. What version of Windows Phone you develop for?

Comment: I tried my code, it still shows blue dots. I am using Windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change the `<Style>`

> Document Outline > Right Click Progress Bar > Edit Template -> Edit A Copy

Look for

```XAML
<Rectangle x:Name="E1" Fill="{ThemeResource ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
```

Change the Fill to any color you like

Repeat for Rectangle E2,E3,E4,E5

---

Or if you can just override `ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush`

In App.xaml, like so

```XAML
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Yellow" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this method copy and paste a whole progress style to my xaml file. Is there a better way so that I just overload the definition of ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush color?

Comment: @hap497 yes, you can override the `ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush` in the App.xaml, see updated solution.

Comment: Overriding `ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush` will change the color of all indeterminate progress bars in the app. I'd rather suggest replacing `Fill="{ThemeResource ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush}"` with `Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"`, so you can use `Foreground` property.